Reopening "is the hard problem of consciousness a bad question"
If the hard problem of consciousness is unanswerable, is it a hard problem or just a bad question?
This is a perfectly legitimate philosophical question. It is not some fringe position; as mentioned in the question, a substantial minority of academic philosophers believe there is no hard problem. The question is popular, having 6 upvotes. Why was it closed? Let's reopen it.
I hesitate to do this unilaterally, so if you get 4 reopen votes tag me and I will be the 5th.

Im not trying to start a conspiracy here but pretty much any question no matter what the content posted by me gets 2-3 close votes quickly at this point. People like @Dcleve also noticed this. How does one prevent someone closing a question because they don’t like me vs. the content of the question?

"no matter what the content". Not true. The content is all that matters. You just ask consistently outside the topic of this site. What other reaction would be reasonable to somebody consistently asking off-topic questions than to close their questions quickly?

@tkruse His question is fully on topic.

Several close voters were of a different opinion. So who is right?

@tkruse The truth is not a majority vote. The hard problem of consciousness is of course on topic. Even the close voters did not claim the question was off topic.

There were 5 close votes. At the moment there are 4 reopen votes.

Tnx Causative for taking this up

I guess I should be more clear on what I thank for @causative. As a mod, you can of course unilaterally open/close any question, delete any answer. My thanks is for your "asking" this meta question which escalates and reifies the silly war which has been going on for a bit between the reflex VTC-ers and the reopeners

The (main) question pointed out in the 1st line above is now open. If your (meta) "question" is about that (main) alone  then you may want to close (this meta) now.  If however you believe that there is a wider systemic misuse of VTC powers by a select bunch of users which is implied but not explicit in your question, you (may) want to amend accordingly

@causative: every close vite means off-topic in my understanding, even if the question is about philosophy. Off-topic means this site requires more clarity, more focus, no duplication... The topic of the question is not the only criteria to be on-topic. I don't know how else you want to describe "that which makes a question worth closing".

I guess your opinion is the only opinion that matters to you. And as I explained a question can be off-topic even if it about a philosophy topic. Being a duplicate as an example. Or being too broad.

@tkruse at the end of the day, the question has a lot of upvotes and it was also re opened. Therefore, by your own love for consensus, you must now admit that the question is a perfectly acceptable one, and thus the complaints about it are ill founded

Upvotes are not a sign of quality, only popularity. And a question that is closed and reopened any number of times I would not consider "perfectly" acceptable, but rather barely so, pending the next closing.

@tkruse “Upvotes are not a sign of quality, only popularity” Oh, but close votes are a sign of bad quality? You’re contradicting yourself

For me, the question cannot be whether a question is philosophical. Almost every question that does not have a clear-cut matter-of-factly answer can be called philosophical. Yet, it cannot be our standard to allow all questions that are philosophical and invite discussion as well as diametrically opposing answers where there cannot be any standard to decide the quality beyond personal preference.
Rather, the question on this site should be will this question likely be able to solicit an answer based on expert knowledge that can be verified by publicly available sources?
In other words, if the answer will likely be opinion, common sense, or is easily accessible via public sources, the question simply is a bad fit. There is more than enough on Meta.SE and in the help center to back this view up.
If the question asked for arguments from both sides, fine. But it almost explicitly makes an assumption and just asks "am I right?". I don't care which close reason is chosen, if the question should be closed, it should remain closed.

The question can indeed be answered definitively by reference to Chalmers' work. The hard problem as defined by Chalmers is answerable. See my answer: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/119623/if-the-hard-problem-of-consciousness-is-unanswerable-is-it-a-hard-problem-or-ju/119669#119669

@causative Yet another example of a good answer to a bad question IMHO

So when a lot of people upvote a question or decide to re-open it, the consensus is irrelevant and it’s a bad question. But when a lot of people want it closed, the consensus is what matters, and it’s a bad question. Which is it?

In a world that is not black and white, there is such a thing as "controversial questions", evidenced by closing and reopening.

@tkruse And in a world of an activist minority there's such a thing as cooked up controversies

@Syed This is not some popularity contest. It's about the model and purpose of this network in general and this site as part of the network in particular. You can have a majority of people being clueless about how this site should be used and it's still wrong.

@PhilipKlöcking I mean I basically agree with you, I’m just saying that there is nothing preventing people from VTC based on reasons that don’t have to do with the site, so it can effectively turn into a popularity contest (not saying it does every time though). Lastly, I made that comment because tkruse mentioned that the only way to judge quality is simply based on what the audience of the site thinks

No, that's only how negative votes work. I believe positive votes are worthless. They are not symmetrical in actual usage, and don't have opposite meanings I. How they are used. While many downvotes very likely means a question is bad, many upvotes means a question is popular. Questions can be both bad an popular at the same time.

@PhilipKlöcking This link discusses what a good subjective question is:  https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/  Based on these principles, I have considered that if a question can have one or several good answers, then it is a good question for our site.

@Dcleve Do you see any inconsistencies with what I wrote? The post existed before even I became moderator IIRC.

@PhilipKlöcking -- from the list, I consider the question to satisfy 1-3, halfway on 4, not really on 5 but almost no questions satisfy 5, and it satisfies 6.  It produced a fair number of answers, and most are good.  Good questions in philosophy produce more than one answer.  So I don't see how this is a bad question that produced one good answer, which is what you said in a comment.  It instead looks to me like a good question that produced multiple good answers.

@PhilipKlöcking while I largely agree with you, I feel like in some sense we're (and I include myself here) just closing questions based on improper framing. It feels silly making a big deal over the difference between "is X?" vs "what are some arguments for X" vs "what are arguments for and against X". I think it might suffice in these cases to propose an edit to the phrasing, since I think the framing matters a lot to some of us and not-much to others?

As I've said elsewhere, I agree that when possible one should reach for the edit button rather than the close button and try to improve the question. I am really not convinced that will reliably be taken as constructive on this stack; the exact wording of a question matters more here than elsewhere, and there is no channel to privately suggest an edit.
