How to Vote-To-Reopen
UPDATE
After consideration of JonathanZ's suggestion that MathSE has a better mechanism for consideration than mine, and Kaia's sentiments which countervail my own, I think the better of the two approaches is MathSE as https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34447/requests-for-reopen-undeletion-votes-volume-01-2022-today.
JonathanZ seems offer not just a solution, but an endorsement of its utility. Votes on this post are +4 and -3, so hopefully the +4 crowd will consider JonathanZ's recommendations.

I've added a vote-to-reopen tag in meta with the ambition of encouraging other contributors who find the VTC mechanism vexatious to rally around a single tag that can be watched. Whether or not anyone other than me uses it will of course be an empirical question. It is my hope that those contributors who push back on absurd VTCs will use this tag to signal to me at first site that there is yet another silly VTC.
Three examples of silly VTCs.

Many years ago, a Q about the term 'disposition' was asked and VTC struck citing it as off-topic. I came to meta and made the case that the presence of the SEP article Dispositions should be prima facie evidence that questions about dispositions as on-topic. (See Friends, how could a question about an idea with its own article in the Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy be closed as off-topic?).
Recently, a question Kristian Berry (now sadly user40843) posited in his usual syntactically challenging asyndetic way the core of a good philosophical question about the philosophical basis of promises. It was VTC, arguably his style isn't the clearest, but partially on the basis that the difference between an oath and a promise isn't a philosophical question (despite the philosophical paper he cited which assured us it was). After poking around, not only is there an article in the SEP Promises, but it has a section devoted to exploring the difference.
Syed recently asked a question about the objectivity and subjectivity of various versions of probability. It wasn't phrased in the clearest language, but clearly, the objectivity and subjectivity of various ways of interpreting probability is perhaps one of the central themes of, yes again, the SEP's Interpretations of Probability.

There clearly id a contingent who is adamant about precision of language, and I respect that. There clearly also is a contingent who seem to lack the basic self-skepticism to differentiate what philosophers study in philosophy professionally, and what they personally believe is philosophy. I find that lack of humility vexatious.
My suggestion is when silly VTCs occur, tag the issue in the metapost with the vote-to-reopen and make a brief case since sometimes those who push VTC also work through the queues and eliminate reopen consideration on posts before those of us who seem to prefer simply relying on the IEP, SEP, REP, PhilPapers, and other professionally created philosophical references sources to help make decisions.
I can't compel anyone to do so, but all it takes is 7-10 people who are frustrated with the VTC mechanism to periodically scan meta and cut down on the excessively militaristic use of the VTC mechanism. I'm buoyed by some recent new blood that seems to want to take a more active role in policing the database to produce quality.
0.02f

Some more for your consideration https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6087/
https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6084/
https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6049/
https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5542/
https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6071/
https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6042/
https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6041/

I think it may be worth considering bifurcatng into 2 levels of discussion: The generic divergence on how the VTC is to be wielded. And the specific when applied to this or that question. This is because (right now) one particular user is driving the meta discussion on VTCs around his closed questions. This (imbalance) is then being exploited by the serial VTC (mis)users as justification to carry on as they do.

Another one for consideration: https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6128/80226

I don't think we should have this tag.
The current tag [[closed-questions]] is neutral language that indicates a question

Is/was closed
There is some question about that.

In contrast, [[vote-to-reopen]] is biased and the idea is that there's no need to even have a discussion in the first place. That only makes sense if absolutely every closed question should be open, which clearly isn't true.
Secondly, it doubles down on the idea that some "close mafia" is closing questions and we need sheer force of numbers to defeat them. I don't think this is true, and it's unkind to users who take the time to moderate the site to say that all their decisions are in error. I think it's much more realistic to say that sometimes we disagree, and by talking it out we can come to consensus.

It's true that incendiary language — mafia etc — increases heat whilst decreasing light. Nevertheless your answer only underscores @JD s implicit point viz. The community is divided on how to wield the close vote. I agree that wielding force of numbers should not ossify to a perennial semi hot war. Discussion is obviously preferable

Note though that it's already late for this discussion: If a top 4 category user left after his question closed, it's almost certain that many more lower rep, less voluble users would have also left or at least throttled back their participation

After examining the MathSE strategy, I've been converted to your approach. Not on the basis of your contrarianism, of course. Whether people believe there's a "VTC mafia" seems to have no bearing on the question: how do we deal with a stream of closure which obviously includes a considerable portion whose closure would seem suspect. For the record, Hanlon's razor undermines claims of a "VTC mafia".

Fine. You win. :P

I'd suggest [meta-tag:reopen-request] if we want to get more specific about it. Maybe that's a bit "less neutral", but it accurately reflects what the Meta questions usually are: requests to reopen questions (requests that can be discussed and may or may not be accepted). It follows a similar naming as [meta-tag:feature-request]. Although I don't know that there's really a need for an additional tag - Meta doesn't exactly get many questions (14 this year... although half of that is in the last month, which is still little, and I don't know how many were deleted).

If people are interested in creating a mechanism like this on phil.se, they might want to check out the way math.se implements something very similar:
https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34447/requests-for-reopen-undeletion-votes-volume-01-2022-today
Keeping it all in one thread seems like an attractive feature.
Of course, the volume of questions on math.se is much greater than the volume here, so what works there might not work here. Also, math.se has a pretty strong standard of professionalism, and people are expected to limit discussion in that thread to quality and site-appropriateness. Whereas here the culture of insulting people who assess questions differently seems pretty strong, so that might make it not work here? Or who knows, maybe pushing all the grar into one thread is precisely what might make it perfect for here? Anyways, I think it's worth checking out.

Quite apart from volume, math (along with stackoverflow (the original) superuser, askubuntu etc, are at the opposite end of the STEM spectrum from philosophy. Most mathematicians will broadly agree on what falls properly outside of math. In philosophy, demarcation is a fundamental open intra-philosophy problem. Therefore using it as though solved in the close/delete claims is patently self contradictory.

You might be surprised at how lively the debate over what is and isn't appropriate for posting on math.se can get on math.se.

I think you convinced me the MathSE strategy is a far better approach on account it reduces clutter.

@JD - Excellent! I think the math.se implementation didn't require any special mod actions to put in place (unlike the sandbox for drafts), so I guess you can just create that post. Are you going to contact the mods with your intentions before doing it? I think getting their buy-in would really help this work. Good luck!

A community like this needs answerers more than askers. Protecting the interests of answerers is more important than protecting the interests of askers.
VTC is the only way answerers can currently defend against askers not respectful about the time of volunteers offering help here.
If the attempts by answerers to protect their time as volunteers is thwarted by mods and self-proclaimed knights in shiny armor, nothing good will happen. It will not attract more good answerers, and not yield better content.
A closed question (in particular one with sufficient answers already) is a victimless situation. It's not a problem that needs fixing. No matter how on-topic a closed question is, keeping it closed does not cause harm.

I really don't think we should push identities of "askers" or "answerers"--most people do a lot of both.

I just count people who do both as "answerers". Or as being part of both groups. There is no consistency issue with either (nobody keeps asking themselves question on this site and gets annoyed with their own questions, voting to close them).

While I agree with the premise argued here, I disagree on the implementation of VTC in multiple specific cases.  VTC has happened with highly upvoted questions, which have multiple highly rated answers.   Therefore, VTC is often demonstrably DIS respectful of answerers, and our community in general.  If there is even one good answer posted on a question, then I believe VTC voters should have 2nd thoughts.  And no, a closed question is not victimless.  It and its answers will be viewed less than open questions.

There's an interesting article from way back in the early years of SE, from one of the founders, "Pearls not sand", that argues along the same lines. One can easily say that things have changed, or what's appropriate to StackOverflow isn't the best for here, but I found it interesting for the way it thought about making a good Q/A site.

My thinking is that answers can simply abstain from answering. However, there certainly are some contributors who find an incessant stream of variations on a theme bothersome.

"And no, a closed question is not victimless. It and its answers will be viewed less than open questions." And that matters how? This is not a blogging platform. Anyone seeking to be seen should be using a blogging platform.

So what did you intend to mean with your claim of "protecting the interests of answerers".  There is little value to answerers in writing an answer that will not be seen!

This parses as a personal put down combined with a very blatantly false rationalization.  If answerers did not care if they were read or not, there would be no need for any of us to publish here at all, and there would be no need whatsoever to "protect the interests of answerers".

the visibility from a closed question is exactly what you deserve and get from this site. It's not any less than advertised. And there is no need to publish here, or anywhere else. But if you seek an audience, this is one of the worst places. From https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic: "Please note that this site is not a personal blog or a pulpit for you to express your own personal philosophical beliefs". Which part of that do you not get?
