How is this question about contemporary Platonist scientists opinion-based and not about philosophy?
The question has 4 close votes as of now and the 5th close vote is likely around the corner (it's just a matter of time). So, how is it opinion-based and not about philosphy?

EDIT: It's closed now.

I think it might be more relevant to https://hsm.stackexchange.com/

Seems fine to me. Philosophy-related, and I can see how it would be worth knowing from a philosophy perspective rather than just a history perspective.

Three of the 4 close votes to date say it is not about philosophy, only one says it is opinion based.  What mechanism Platonist physicists postulate holds for abstraction/matter interaction is pretty clearly on-subject for philosophy though -- the close voters are clearly wrong.  That there is no answer, just as there is no clear answer about what matter IS, or how matter interacts with itself, or how mind might interact with matter, are important philosophical issues as well.

Question is now closed.

@causative - A lot of things are worth knowing from a philosophy perspective. Shall I now start flooding the site by repeating all SEP articles in question format? -- The specific question was initially just historical and can be answered (insofar as answers are available) by some simple lookups. I would also not have minded one or two of those kind of questions - but this user is what I call "flooding" the site with non-specific traditional questions for which several traditional answers are available all around. What purpose does merely repeating those kind of questions serve here ...

... apart from only asking for people's opinions? In the past I never liked that reason for closing questions -- I would not have believed that  someone could bring me to see the light...

By their own admission the OP doesn't have their own opinion and is merely "probing" for answers. Which effectively means that all posts have the form: "Some philosophers have said this. Some have said that. What do y'all think?"  -- If that's not asking for opinions rather than factual answers, I don't know what it is. And I'm curious if anyone doesn't agree with my summary to hear in which way the posts have gone beyond that.

If the OP wants to continue doing so -- I'd advise them to have a look at the link @Conifold gave. The conclusions of that thesis can all be translated into questions that would probably interest the OP, and that are directly relevant for the questions that the OP seems to want to probe us about, but that at least seem kind of original and fresh, rather than stale. Provocatively put: Are string theories a new form of mathematical kabbalah? Is the urge to use math in physics actually a form of theology?

@mudskipper "Some philosophers have said this. Some have said that. What do y'all think?" - no, that's not what the question is about in this case. In this case they are asking which philosophers said a thing. (Or which physicists said it; but a physicist expressing a cogent opinion on how Platonism relates to physics, is also a philosopher.)

@causative 4 reopen votes :)

The question originally included the word 'popular', so I commented that popularity has no relevance to the truth of a proposition. It was my hint that he was asking for opinions, although, yes, ones from authoritative sources, ahem. Also irrelevant.

Perhaps if you let us know what you are actually trying to accomplish by asking one question after another about the precise wording of previous questions, answers, comments and outside sources, maybe we could help? Instead of shaking every tree, just say what it is you really want. Saying you're just trying to learn or something begs the question: learn what? What motivates the questions(s)?

Let's see with the title:
"Are there notable" - notable or not is a matter of opinion
"contemporary" contemporary or not is a matter of opinion. (Also this would change as time passes and people die and their death moves away from the present)
"scientists and physicists" whether any person is a scientist and a physicist is a matter of opinion
"Who are mathematical Platonists?" Again matter of opinion.
Whether such people exist on the planet is a matter if census, like are there red haired people named John Smith in Alaska. Certainly whether such people exist or not is not about philosophy.
That's just the title.
The body: "what solutions have they proposed to the causal interaction problem between the Platonic and the physical?"
Now given I have established that this awkwardly definited set of people is very much opinion based, how then can anyone make a list of statements from that set of people. This could be 3 people, or 3000. How can an answer be complete unless it gives full attention to anyone anyone else might seem contemporary, or scientists, or whatnot. On this site we cannot even agree on whether flatearthism is science.

I see at least two areas where some form of causal interaction arguably should exist

This is blogging about a personal opinion, and asking for other opinions on that opinion. Pretty much opinion based.
One might notice how the question title is asking about whether people exist, whereas the body asks about a summary of what an undefinable set of people said that based on opinion could be seen as contributing to the subject. This difference between title question and body question does not help with quality.
Now this question could probably be redeemed in all those points, removing all the awkwardness, but even then likely what would be left would be a duplicate of an existing question.
At some point the effort of trying to fix a question is too much compared to just starting from scratch.
So just learn how to ask precisely instead of building awkward question constructs.

Yes, yes, and yes on all points...

And the question originally asked for popular views, which of course didn't stand for long.
